# Capistrano: Killed RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets bundle exec rake assets:precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, assets, production

I was dealing with this issue the whole yesterday's afternoon, I found for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15035846/capistrano-killing-assetsprecompile) topic, which didn't work out for me.

Then I found a topic here on SO, where was given an advise to add `load 'deploy/assets'` to `Capfile`. Finally, it worked!

But this morning when I tried to deploy another code, I got again this error:

```
 ** [out :: IP] bash: line 1: 15213 Killed                  RAILS_ENV=staging RAILS_GROUPS=assets bundle exec rake assets:precompile
    command finished in 38500ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
```

I drives me crazy, yesterday was everything well, but today - all of sudden - again the same error. Here's my setup:

Capfile:

```
load 'deploy'
load 'config/deploy' # remove this line to skip loading any of the default tasks
load 'deploy/assets'
```

deploy/production.rb:

```
...
namespace :deploy do

  task :setup_config, roles: [:app] do
    sudo "ln -nfs #{current_path}/config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/app"
    sudo "ln -nfs #{current_path}/config/unicorn_init_production.sh /etc/init.d/unicorn_app-production"
    run "mkdir -p #{shared_path}/config"
    put File.read("config/database.yml"), "#{shared_path}/config/database.yml"
    puts "Now edit the config files in #{shared_path}."
  end
  after "deploy:setup", "deploy:setup_config"

  task :symlink_config, roles: [:app] do
    run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/config/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
  end
  after "deploy:finalize_update", "deploy:symlink_config"
  after "deploy:create_symlink", "deploy:restart"

  desc "Make sure local git is in sync with remote."
  task :check_revision, roles: [:web] do
    unless `git rev-parse HEAD` == `git rev-parse origin/master`
      puts "WARNING: HEAD is not the same as origin/master"
      puts "Run `git push` to sync changes."
      exit
    end
  end
  %w[stop].each do |command|
    desc "#{command} unicorn server"
    task command, roles: :app, except: {no_release: true} do
      run "/etc/init.d/unicorn_app-production #{command}"
    end
  end


  %w[restart].each do |command|
    desc "#{command} unicorn server"
    task command, roles: :app, except: {no_release: true} do
      run "/etc/init.d/unicorn_app-production #{command}"
    end
  end

  before "deploy", "deploy:check_revision"  
end
```

deploy.rb:

```
require "capistrano/ext/multistage"
require "rvm/capistrano"
require 'bundler/capistrano'
require 'delayed/recipes' # added for running deplayed jobs

set :application, 'app'
set :bundle_flags, "--quiet --no-cache"

set :scm, :git
default_run_options[:pty] = true
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :repository, 'git@bitbucket.org:name/repo.git'
set :branch, "master"
set :pty, true
set :keep_releases, 5
```

I'd be very helpful for every advise!

Thank you guys

**EDIT: environments/production.rb**

```
App::Application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.eager_load = true

  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.serve_static_assets = true

  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  config.assets.compile = false
  config.assets.precompile = ['*.js', 'application.css', 'styles.css.scss', '*.css.erb']
  config.assets.precompile += %w(*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif *.svg *.woff *.ttf *.ico)
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.assets.version = '1.2'
  config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx
  config.log_level = :info
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'http://www.app.com' }
end
```

Comment: server kill process, look into the `dmesg` on server, i think you have  no memory for compile.

Comment: You mean - RAM memory?

Comment: Yes, what *say* `dmesg`, compile assets very huge for memory.

Comment: The last two lines: `[5689488.101760] Out of memory: Kill process 31427 (ruby) score 184 or sacrifice child
[5689488.102528] Killed process 31427 (ruby) total-vm:948244kB, anon-rss:235856kB, file-rss:0kB`. So far on the server I had 1GB, I'll try to double it.

Comment: you can compile assets localy and move to the server, without upgrade memory.if i help can i post answer for you?

Comment: How can I compile them locally? Just `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` and commit + deploy? Of course, post it please as an answer and I will obviously accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Server kill process, look into the `dmesg` on server, i think you have no memory for compile.
`dmesg` return:

> [5689488.101760] Out of memory: Kill process 31427 (ruby) score 184 or
>   sacrifice child [5689488.102528] Killed process 31427 (ruby)
>   total-vm:948244kB, anon-rss:235856kB, file-rss:0kB

You can compile assets localy and move to the server, without upgrade memory.

Look this [`gist`](https://gist.github.com/keighl/4338134) or this [`gem`](https://github.com/spagalloco/capistrano-local-precompile).

Comment: if I run `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` and then commit/push it + deploy it, I still see the same error message: `bash: line 1:  2683 Killed                  RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

Comment: you should disable precompile assets on server, try comment `load  'deploy/assets'` in `Capfile`. And precompile assets in production env `bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`

Comment: Hmm... this caused that the deployment is okay now, but on the website are missing some images (and CSS icons) - won't be the problem commenting `load  'deploy/assets'`?

Comment: `load  'deploy/assets'` it is just hooks for asset compile, show `production.rb` and what proxy-server you use `nginx` or `apache`?

Comment: Updated original question about the `production.rb`. I am using `nginx`.

Comment: remove all assets and try again. I advise use local precompile gem, you configuration looks good, this is all what i can help you.